# 'undo' or 'cancel' dockerfile VOLUME to share mysql DB in registry

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I'm inheriting from the mysql Dockerfile and want to move a VOLUME (/var/lib/mysql) back inside the container so I can distribute it from a registry.

Is there a way in my downstream Dockerfile to (a) undo the VOLUME declaration or (b) replace /var/lib/mysql with a symlink?

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving up on this -- seems simpler to distribute a zipped copy of the DB data directory. If you have a better option, please post.

Comment: Posting for any future viewers, **do not** ship your database data blob inside of your database image. This is an antipattern and will create problems for you almost immediately. The "right" way to do this is either shipping a dump and restoring with the dump, or shipping an archive/zip of the data blob (and mounting from the host into the container) as mentioned here, or really any other way that keeps your container images clean and auditable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, just with another database (arangodb).

However, I did not find a direct solution for this problem, but in my case (this should also work with mysql), I simply changed the data directory of my database to a non-volume directory in the Dockerfile.

For now, this seems like the best solution, as you can build a full image that contains your data.

Answer (score 0):

As L0j1k has argued vividly in general it is a very bad idea to have your data dir inside of the container. However there are situations where it makes sense. Like for automated tests, run a container with testdata check that everything works as expected and throw it away. Also on OSX & Windows volumes aren't native mounds (because docker runs in a VM) and they can be painfully slow. So you might be better of with copying your data from and to the container, depending on your situation.

While you can't undo the VOLUME directive you can simply create a new data dir and tell Mysql to use that:

```
FROM mariadb:latest

# Create data dir in /var/lib/data
RUN mkdir /var/lib/data
RUN chown mysql.mysql /var/lib/data

# Change data dir from /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/data
RUN sed -i 's/\/var\/lib\/mysql/\/var\/lib\/data/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Use with caution.

Answer (score -1):

**DO NOT** ship your database data in the same image as your database! This is an antipattern and will create bigger problems almost immediately. Ship the data *separately* as an archive which you then mount into your database container via bind-mount (`-v /home/foo/db:/var/lib/mysql`). Bind-mount volumes in your `docker run` statement will override any `VOLUME` Dockerfile directive. Alternatively, create some automation to dump the database and ship that to your containers, then restore using the dump. Whatever you do will be better than creating an image with your data in the database image. Just as one example of why this is a bad idea: What happens when you need to move the data/database mutant which now has changes? You'll probably use `docker export` to dump the entire container's filesystem into a new image, and now you're passing around a big blob of crap which is hard to audit. Docker containers (and microservices in general) are designed to be *ephemeral* and stateless, which means you can hose any one container and recreate it and it'll continue working. You can't do this if you ship your blob of data inside the database image.

With respect to the `VOLUME` directive in that Dockerfile: Remember that Dockerfiles are used during `docker build` and therefore do not (and cannot) contain host-dependent information or actions. So the `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql` isn't making your image impossible to distribute. What [that directive does](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) is create a generic (i.e. non-bind-mount) data volume that persists the data of that directory beyond the lifetime of the container. It is *not* the same thing as a bind-mount volume for example in `docker run -v "/var/docker/app/data:/var/lib/mysql" ...`. This Dockerfile directive does not prevent you from distributing the image because it does not specify host-dependent information.

Comment: it makes the DB's data directory impossible to distribute from a registry. I understand that the built image can still be pushed & pulled -- but without the data inside it that doesn't help me.

Comment: Are you implying that you're trying to ship the database directory inside of your image? There are many shark fins in those waters, my friend.

Comment: I have same issue but with PHP - base image has VOLUME /var/www/html and I want to add app sources in this directory in build.

Comment: The [PHP base image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/fd8e15250a0c7667b161c34a25f7916b01f72367/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile) has `WORKDIR /var/www/html`. That is not the same as `VOLUME`. The effect of `WORKDIR` is effectively like the `cd` command, it just makes that location your pwd. You would have no problems shipping files in that directory as part of the image.

Comment: Lots of people here are suggesting to ship the database data with the database image, which is an antipattern. *Do not* ship your database data inside of your database image. Source files for a site (like in `/var/www/html`) are okay because they're stateless, but it's important to explicitly say that database data (like in `/var/lib/mysql`) should be shipped separately. People new to Docker and microservice architectures feel that this is the right answer to ship the data and the database in one image, but it is not.